# Bitbucket cloning private git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone

I want to clone a private git repository on `bitbucket`, but I don't have an `ssh-key` on my workstation yet. When I try to clone I get the following:

```
Cloning into 'notdefinedyet'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Must I generate a new `ssh-key` or can I get an old key which was installed earlier? If so, how I can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a copy of your private key available, you will have to generate a new one and associate it on your account.  There's no way to get the private key back, that's what makes them private.